# How to solve date format problem when using Window XP in C?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am using Window 7, when I run my code in local everything is alright, but when upload to Window server 2003 the code will coming error:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

My computer setting (date format) all same with my window server. Still come out the same problem.

below is my code:

```
dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("12-6-2011");

dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime("18-6-2011");

//or    
dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("12-6-2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dateTo = DateTime.ParseExact("18-6-2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//i using parse also din come out.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how this relates to the 'C' language, so I may have misinterpreted something. However, you are using the wrong format string as far as I can see.

If your dates always look like that, try using a format string like "d-M-yyyy".

Have a look at the following page for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: thank for sharing i solve my problem through your link although not relates with C language Xp.haha

Answer (score 0):

MM stands for month. You shoud use dd/MM/yyyy to fit your data.

Comment: The separator is not a slash (U.S), but a dash (ISO). From the documentation it appears you have to specify the separators correctly.

Comment: @Krumelur: date is specified to "18-6-2011", so either change the data format or the data itself. I think it is more reasonable to change the format

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("12-6-2011", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dateTo = DateTime.ParseExact("18-6-2011", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Cannot also same problem coming out ,actually my code is running okay at my local side but window server not accepted by the thanks for telling.